# How to print development debug messages when writing an ansible module?

Tags: ansible

I tried `AnsibleModule.log` but it will send it to system log and I want to see it in the middle of the tasks output

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html

Comment: This is to be used in a playbook, I want something to be used in a module

Answer (score 0):

[The fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/dev_guide/developing_modules_best_practices.html#creating-correct-and-informative-module-output) says not to do what you are asking (citing JSON pollution concerns), but rather to return any debugging messages in the `module.exit_json` `dict` or if you just don't want it use syslog then you can [configure it that way](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/config.html#default-no-target-syslog)

Comment: The messages where mainly development stuff, I endup using ansible_module_results and msg to do this. It seems that the messages to .log go to the target syslog, not the controller one right? If so this is useless during development

Comment: As a side note, what I find out was that the "proper way" of doing this would create an action_plugin with the same name as my module and use Display class there.